# LinqPad Power-Tick

Tags: linqpad

I am trying to use LinqPad's "Power-Tick" feature to multi-select column names I wish to include in my query. For example, if I type:

from c in Customers
select new {c.

At that point a popup appears. Shouldn't that be the popup that lets me use "power-tick"? If so, how do I use it? Whenever I click or choose any item in that popup, it disappears.

(My LinqPad is fully licensed and has autocompletion.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

To use the Power-Tick feature you need to use the backtick key (typically next to the number 1 key on your keyboard).

Use this sequence to select multiple items:

1. Select the property via the up/down arrows or the mouse.
2. Press the <kbd>`</kbd> (backtick) key. This will cause the selected property to be filled in your current query, and the menu will remain open.
3. Select another property and repeat the process till all desired properties have been selected.

In other words, when selecting an item use the backtick key. Don't use the <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd> keys since those will select the item and then close the menu.

Comment: That worked! Now I see that the menu has text that says "press [backtick key] to select multiple items" but that is not actually what the [backtick key] does. You can never select multiple items; what you can do is select a single item and use [backtick key] instead of enter to add that item to the list and keep the popup open. Also, if you just hit [backtick key] repeatedly, you end up entering values in the sequence in which they appear in the popup since the selection automatically advances to the next item whenever you hit [backtick key].

Thank you very much for your help!